# How to send a value from a html page to php page with text validation

Tags: php, javascript, html

After searching for my stuff, I didn't found much usefull info on other Websites or forums.So decided to ask a straight question here.
I have a html file which checks the field is empty or not, if empty it gives a alert, eyerthing is fine uptill here.My question is how to send the text value to the php page if the text box is not empty.My passwordres.html file goes like this:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<form onsubmit="return checkvalue()" method="post">
<ul class=mainForm id="mainForm_1"> 
<li class="mainForm" >Enter your Email address :</li>  
<input name="FNAME" type="text" id="mystring"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Proccedd" />
</form></ul></div>
<script lang="javascript">
 function checkvalue() { 
 var a = document.getElementById('mystring').value;
 if(!(a).match(/\S/)) {
    alert ('Empty value is not allowed');
    return true;
}
else
 {
 window.open("http://...Secured.php?mystring="//value here""); 
return false;}
 }
</script>
```

Any help would be greatfull.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use jquery ajax, post or get to sending value from jquery to php api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/‎

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the `a` variable to your url like:

```
window.open("http://...Secured.php?mystring="+a);
```

It will easily get by Secured.php by:

```
$_GET['mystring']
```

**Edit:**
This is not right way to pass string from form. `return true` will allow the form to submit and you will get the value by `$_POST['FNAME']`. You also need to validate that in server side.

Comment: Your answer works and you're showing what he wants, but you know that this is not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery ajax.

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
   name  =$("#name").val();
   if(name==""){
      alert("Name Required!");
   }else{
      $.ajax({
         url:'page.php',
         data:'name='+name,
         success(result){
           alert(result);
         }
      });
   }
 });
```

You need to include jquery library in your html page.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send data from your form where you want using this

```
<form action="http://...Secured.php" onsubmit="return checkvalue()" method="post">
```

instead of this one

```
<form onsubmit="return checkvalue()" method="post">
```

And there you can refer to a variable like this

```
$_POST['variable_name_from_form']
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing window.open. you can simply return false if field is empty else return true. and in form add attribute action with php page name. Something like this.

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<form action="http://...Secured.php" onsubmit="return checkvalue()" method="post">
<ul class=mainForm id="mainForm_1"> 
<li class="mainForm" >Enter your Email address :</li>  
<input name="FNAME" type="text" id="mystring"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Proccedd" />
</form></ul></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkvalue() { 
 var a = document.getElementById('mystring').value;
 if(a=="" || a==null) {
    alert ('Empty value is not allowed');
    return false;
}
else
 {
 return true;
 }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Here's new chanllenge, I don't wont to load the Secured.php page Means when the field is empty, by your codes even it gives an alert but also goes to Secured.php...,? ANY HELP

Comment: Sinply i want the same page(passwordres.html) to be shown when user lefts the field empty or if he enters his email only then & then the Secured.php will open..?

Comment: I dont want even a "space" or "space"="null",means even a space is counted as empty, that's what i want.

Comment: no worries, you may use your own criteria i.e. **!(a).match(/\S/)** in place of **a=="" || a==null**.